# 'MSIAuthentication' object has no attribute 'get_token'

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

On Azure ML Workspace Notebook, I'm trying to get my workspace instance, as seen at

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-auto-train-models#configure-workspace.](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azureml.ipynb)

I have a config file and I am running the notebook in an Azure compute instance.

I tried to execute Workspace.from_config().

As a result, I'm getting the 'MSIAuthentication' object has no attribute 'get_token' error.

I tried to submit both `MsiAuthentication` and `InteractiveLoginAuthentication`, as suggested in

[https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azureml.ipynb.](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azureml.ipynb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are 2 solutions I've found:**

1.- Use the kernel "Python 3.6 - AzureML"

2.- `pip install azureml-core --upgrade`

This will **upgrade**

> azureml-core to 1.32.0

But will **downgrade**:

> azure-mgmt-resource to 13.0.0 (was 18.0.0)

> azure-mgmt-storage down to 11.2.0 (was 18.0.0)

> urllib3 to 1.26.5 (was 1.26.6)

This upgrade / downgrade allows the same package versions as in the python 3.6 anaconda install

Comment: If there are some unmet versions. Following command helped me: pip install azureml-sdk[notebooks]
Source: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/87272/failure-while-loading-azureml-run-type-providers.html